# I am trying to run "npm link" in my terminal and I keep getting an error

Tags: javascript

This is the error I keep getting:

[image: error]

Please can someone assist me with this?

Thanks in advance.

I'm working on a Mac, with Vs Code as my editor and iTerm as my terminal.

I have updated my vs Code, updated my Node, and went through deleted all the files in the directory I was trying to working and restarted multiple times. I still cannot get nmp link to work.

Comment: Please include the error as text within the question.

Comment: Looks like a run-of-the-mill file permission error.

Answer (score 0):

You actual issue is running the (globally installed) `watchit` npm package.

Looks like the global node packages are installed in: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, and you don't have permission to execute from that path.

Here is a related article: [*"How to fix EACCES errors with NPM on MacOS"*](https://www.willandskill.se/en/articles/how-to-fix-eacces-errors-with-npm-on-macos)

The suggested solution is to alter the permissions by issuing a `chown` with `sudo` (root):

```bash
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will give this a try and try and resolve this problem.